# css class based on loaded template

Tags: css, go, go-html-template

I've got this bootstrap nav in my _base.html template like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="/" class="">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using Golang I want to add a

```
class="active"
```

to the corresponding list-item.

I've read the [html/template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) docs and articles like [thisone](http://jan.newmarch.name/golang/template/chapter-template.html), but it appears to me that I have to write a golang function that adds

```
class="active"
```

to every correspondending corresponding list-item. But somehow still I think it would be cleaner if I could just add something like

```
<ul>
    <li{{ if .template = "index.html" }} class="active"{{ end }}><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li{{ if .template = "blog.html" }} class="active"{{ end }}><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

or something like that. I remember Rob Pike saying Golang should be doing all the calculations for you, but why is there an "if" statement in the html/template-package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally often implement a small `eq` helper for tasks like that:

```
var tmpl = template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "eq": func(a, b interface{}) bool {
        return a == b
    },
}).ParseGlob("templates/*.html")
```

Example Usage:

```
<li{{if eq .Active "index"}} class="active"{{end}}><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

But use it only for the display logic itself. It's a good practice to keep the display logic and the real computation apart.

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays you don't have to implement your own `eq` helper. It is already included in the [template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package.

```
<ul>
  <li {{if eq .Active "info" }}class="active"{{end}}>
    <a href="/info">{{.User.Info}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now render this template with an anonymous struct.

```
// get template from file
view := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
  "views/info.html",
  "views/layout.html",
))

// render template with data in route handler
data := struct {
  User   *User  // some custom struct with further details
  Active string
}{
  user,  // a User instance
  "info",
}
err = view.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout", data)
check(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the way to go in your case. You can reformulate this slightly differently depending on your exact use case such as:

```
type State struct {
    active string
}
func (s *State) Class(page string) {
    if s.active == page {
        return `class="active"`
    }
    return `class="notactive"` // Or whatever default case you want
}

tmplt = `
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/" {{.Class "index"}}>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/" {{.Class "blog"}}>Blog</a></li>
</ul>`
```

Or something along these lines, but the point of `if` in templates is precisely to allow for these kind of things. Although your Go code will decide WHICH page is active, you still have to pass it to your template, and I think some sort of `if` statement (or call as I did above) is required to **extract** the state you pass, even though it already contains all the information.